# What is the sample rate of my ATmega88's ADC?

Tags: adc, atmega

The sample rate of the ADC of ATmega88 is 15 ksps at 10 bits. If I'm using only 8 bits then what will be the sample rate?
Would it be the same sample rate or it will change from 15 ksps? Will it increase or decrease?

Comment: The data sheet sample rate is a maximum value. To achieve that rate you have to be requesting conversions at that rate or programming the ADC to repeatedly make conversions at that rate. Your software may on the other hand be requesting conversions at a slower rate which is what ultimately results in a different sample rate. Related to maximum sample rate is the time to perform sample and hold and then the A/D conversion. It is this latter that is what is ultimately affected when the clocking of the A/D converter is changed.

Comment: What you'll typically want to do is set the left adjust bit, and read ADCH. The will push the 8 most significant bits into ADCH, and discard the least significant bits. If you actually need the least significant bits, they are there, but will be the top 2 bits of ADCL.

Answer (score 3):

The sample rate of *most* ADCs is completely independent from it's bit resolution.

The number of bits returned by an ADC is a function of it's hardware.
Basically, a 10 bit ADC is a 10 bit ADC. If you're not using some of the bits, it's still a 10 bit ADC.

---

As such, the maximum achievable sample rate with the ADC in the ATmega88 at the full 10-bit resolution is 15 kSPS. *However, you can run the ADC faster, at the expense of increased noise.*

From the ATmega88 docs:

> By default, the successive approximation circuitry requires an input clock frequency between
>   50kHz and 200kHz to get maximum resolution. If a lower resolution than 10 bits is needed, the
>   input clock frequency to the ADC can be higher than 200kHz to get a higher sample rate.

So basically, as the speed at which you clock the ADC increases, the ADC noise increases. As such, if you run the ADC faster then the 15 kSPS, *you still get 10 bit conversion results*, however, **the smaller bits are not valid**, as they are swamped by noise and/or biases in the ADC.

Answer (score 1):

The sample rate will be the same and it is not dependent on converter resolution. Sample rate can be set by changing clock prescaler for the ADC block.